# Improve code to avoid loop and conditions

Tags: if-statement, optimization, refactoring, dry

I am decoding a file and have two functions in my code. The first one is extracting the needed values, that need to be splitted in parts, whereas the second one is decoding the parts and giving the output.

The second function has many if-statements to process the actual right part in the right way, because each part needs to be handled differently.
The statements differ only minimally in output as well as processing due to the length of the chunks.

1. I know the don't-repeat-yourself-principle, but since there are differences in the handling of each part, i don't know how to improve the actual code.
2. Is it good to use one class for each part or should i just split the code into two files like one for extracting the values and one for decoding?
3. Is there another way to loop through the parts and processing them except using a while loop and many if conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can change only some variables on the if's and then at the end, call only 1 time the readRaw and other common code at the end:

```
while (True){

    extract a 
    
    if (a == 100){
        break
    }
    
    if (a == 1){
        offsetVar = 0
        nbytesVar=2
        sizeVar=2
        # other stuff with these values
    }
    
    if (a == 2){
        offsetVar = 2
        nbytesVar=4
        sizeVar=4
        #other stuff with these values
    }
    
    ...
    
    if (a == 29){
        offsetVar = 8
        nbytesVar=2
        sizeVar=2
        # other stuff with these values
    }
    
    #    ONLY 1 TIME CALL COMMON CODE
    this <- readRaw (file = test_filename, offset=offsetVar, nbytes=nbytesVar, size=sizeVar)
    that <- blockValue(this)
    cat(paste("value a is:", a,
                  "other values:", otherValues))
}
```

Comment: @3zm4script Also you can change all those if's with a switch case (less code that many if's)

Comment: The problem is that readRaw and blockValue is called several times in a statement depending on the value of `a`. So in one statement eg it is called once, in another one thrice

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your loop does nothing: your code would already be shorter if you simply removed the loop and the `if`s entirely, and just did everything in sequence:

```
code for a == 1
code for a == 2
…
```

… but of course we can do better. You say that there’s no pattern to your offsets and number of bytes. So put them into lists (vectors won’t work since you need to nest them, as each `a` value can have more than one associated value):

```
offsets = list(
    c(0L, 2L),
    2L,
    8L
)
nbytes = list(
    c(2L, 2L),
    4L,
    2L
)

read_value = function (a, offset, nbytes) {
    this = readRaw(test_filename, offset = offset, nbytes = nbytes)
    that = blockValue(this)
}

do_stuff = function (a, offset, nbytes) {
    value = read_value(a, offset, nbytes)
    # do other stuff with value
    message('value is: ', a, ' other values: ', otherValues)
}

for (a in 1 : 100) {
    mapply(do_stuff, a, offsets[[a]], nbytes[[a]])
}
```

Comment: The loop is there to go through the file, because each time i extract a different `a`. There is a counter after the loop which determines at which point the file should be read further. The counter is composed of other variables within the statements.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of actual code, the seemingly best solution I can give is:

1. Extract the duplicated parts in the code into their own methods and then call the extracted method; This keeps the code DRY.
2. Extract the code in conditional blocks into their own methods<sup>*</sup>. This keeps the high level methods abstract (rather than detailing whole work) and keeps your methods small.

---

<sup>*</sup> Example for point#2:

You can convert some code that looks like below:

```
public void myMethod() {
    if (someCondition) {
        line1;
        line2;
        line3;
    } else if (someOtherCondition) {
        line4;
        line5;
        line6;
    } else {
        line7;
        line8;
        line9;
    }
}
```

to:

```
private void someConditionMethod() {
    line1;
    line2;
    line3;
}

private void someOtherConditionMethod() {
    line4;
    line5;
    line6;
}

private void finalMethod() {
    line7;
    line8;
    line9;
}

public void myMethod() {
    if (someCondition) {
        someConditionMethod();
        return;
    }

    if (someOtherCondition) {
        someOtherConditionMethod();
        return;
    }

    finalMethod();
}
```